# C# How should I use NetworkStream more effectively?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networking

Data packets are sent from `TcpListener` to `TcpClient` via `NetworkStream`. Packets aren't big(5 Bytes) but come with great frequency (about 1000 per second or more). Can you give me advice how should I process it most effective? Now I use async for getting stream, which fill buffer, then I cut it to the packets. After that the process is repeated. But 
at some point I lose true sequence.

`s` is NetworkStream.

Packet has 2 fields: type(1 Byte (byte)) and value(4 Bytes (int))

`MAXVALUEPACKET` = 4096

Client Code:

```
async Task process()
    {
        bool flag = false;
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] actionBuffer;
            flag = false;
            actionBuffer = await ReadFromStreamAsync();
            while (!flag)
            {
                byte type = actionBuffer[0];
                int value = 0;
                if (type > 0)
                {
                    byte[] valueBytes = { actionBuffer[4], actionBuffer[3], actionBuffer[2], actionBuffer[1] };
                    value = BitConverter.ToInt32(valueBytes, 0);
                    actionBuffer = actionBuffer.Skip(5).ToArray();
                    CommonVariables.RawMessages.Add(new KeyValuePair<byte, int>(type, value));
                    OnHandler();
                }
                else
                    flag = true;                     
            }    
        }
    }        
    byte[] buf = new byte[MAXVALUEPACKET];
    async Task<byte[]> ReadFromStreamAsync()
    {
        await s.ReadAsync(buf, 0, MAXVALUEPACKET);
        return buf; 
    }
```

Comment: [`ReadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx): "The value of the *TResult* parameter contains the total number of bytes read into the buffer. The result value can be less than the number of bytes requested if the number of bytes currently available is less than the requested number"

Comment: And, most importantly, the TCP abstraction is a stream of bytes. There's no guarantee that each call of `Send` at one end will be matched 1-1 with a call to `Receive` at the other. If you want "Packets" or "Messages", it's up to *you* to implement framing logic atop TCP, or move to a higher level abstraction.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
Yes, thanks! Read only 5 Bytes, it has become much better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `MAXVALUEPACKET = 5` to read exactly every 5 bytes may help avoid loss of bytes:

```
        const int MAXVALUEPACKET = 5;
        async Task process()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var actionBuffer = await ReadFromStreamAsync();
                byte type = actionBuffer[0];
                int value = 0;
                if (type > 0)
                {
                    byte[] valueBytes = { actionBuffer[4], actionBuffer[3], actionBuffer[2], actionBuffer[1] };
                    value = BitConverter.ToInt32(valueBytes, 0);
                    CommonVariables.RawMessages.Add(new KeyValuePair<byte, int>(type, value));
                    OnHandler();
                }
            }
        }

        async Task<byte[]> ReadFromStreamAsync()
        {
            await s.ReadAsync(buf, 0, MAXVALUEPACKET);
            return buf;
        }
```

The problem of original code logic is when iteration reaches the 820th loop, there is 1 byte left and it makes the logic to read integer value fail. I'm assuming the server always writes exactly 5 bytes in every portions.